# I want to overlay a rectangle on top of another rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to form something like  this using CSS and typescript/JavaScript:

[image: this]

Can someone please help me understand how to do this?

I tried using a flex container and this is what I have got this:

[image: this]

I am new to front end development. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

```css
.green-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: @space-sm;
  position: relative;
}

.black-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 5%;
}

.height {
  height: @space-sm;
}
```

```html
<div styleName="green-area">
  <div style={{ flexGrow: 10, }}>
    <div styleName={`height`}>
      <div styleName="black-area">
        <div style={{ flexGrow: 10, }}>
          <div styleName={`height`} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `styleName`? Did you mean `className`? At any rate, this type of thing is best addressed with rendered HTML. It would be easier to help if you'd update the snippet demo above with that rather than JSX. It's an HTML/CSS issue at its core.

Comment: Are you trying to build a [range slider](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)? Why not just use that?

Comment: @ManojBhat, it's not my post. JSX won't show in an HTML demo. See my first comment.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like `isherwood` mentioned, this is an HTML/CSS issue.

- You've added the class using `styleName` which is incorrect. It should be `className`
- You've missed the positioning for the `black-area`

I created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-line-with-marker-f7e3he?file=/src/App.js) with the answer. You can change the inline `style` to control the positioning of the `black-area`